scp not working in a custom python shell script after migration from ubuntu 20.04 to debian 12
I have this backup server where various clients upload daily archives via scp. In order to protect the machine and to manage the backups, I have written a simple python shell script that only allows uploading and listing files.
here are the relevant lines in the script:
cs = (len(sys.argv) == 3 and sys.argv[1] == '-c' and sys.argv[2]) or ''
cmd = cs.split()
cmd0 = (cmd or ('',))[0]
os.environ['PATH'] = '/bin:/usr/bin'
os.environ.pop('DISPLAY', '')  # Disable X11.
os.environ.pop('XDG_SESSION_COOKIE', '')
os.environ.pop('XAUTHORITY', '')

try:
    # This is insecure: os.execl('/bin/sh', 'sh', '-c', cmd)
    result = os.spawnvp(os.P_WAIT, cmd0, cmd)
except OSError:
    print('error: command not found: %s\n' % cmd0, file=sys.stderr)
    sys.exit(1)

I hope I didn't leave anything important out, but the rest is mostly checking this and that and failing if the checks don't pass.
This used to work just fine when the server was Ubuntu 20.04. I have since reinstalled the computer with Debian 12 due to various issues I was suffering and - while I have managed to solve the old issues - now I'm stuck with this one.
This fails for all connection attempts made from the same new machine. It fails trying to switch ssh session to sftp. The response I'm getting is just /usr/bin/scp: Connection closed. There is no additional info in the logs that would be of note.
I have searched around and I found some questions suggesting I need to modify my sshd configuration, change the Subsystem sftp setting, but that of course isn't helping. It is set to Subsystem<----->sftp<-->/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
To make matters worse: this is a problem just for the new computer. I am running the same backup scripts on Linux and Windows machines and they all (still) work when they run this elsewhere.
here's output of scp -vvv for the section where subsystem negotiation starts:
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
debug2: channel 0: request subsystem confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: client_repledge: enter
debug1: pledge: fork
debug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: subsystem request accepted on channel 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: chan_shutdown_write: channel 0: (i0 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: chan_shutdown_read: channel 0: (i0 o3 sock -1 wfd 4 efd 6 [write])
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 [session] r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 sock -1 cc -1 io 0x00/0x00)

and here's the journalctl for the same operation:
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_input_channel_req: session 0 req subsystem
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: subsystem: exec() /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: Starting session: subsystem 'sftp' for jure_backup from 192.168.237.20 port 45094 id 0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: Received SIGCHLD.
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_by_pid: pid 123367
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_exit_message: session 0 channel 0 pid 123367
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_exit_message: release channel 0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_by_channel: session 0 channel 0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: session_close_by_channel: channel 0 child 0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: Close session: user jure_backup from 192.168.237.20 port 45094 id 0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: channel 0: free: server-session, nchannels 1
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: Received disconnect from 192.168.237.20 port 45094:11: disconnected by user
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: Disconnected from user jure_backup 192.168.237.20 port 45094
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: do_cleanup
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1004/1004 (e=1004/1004)
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123366]: debug1: restore_uid: (unprivileged)
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123364]: debug1: do_cleanup
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123364]: debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1004/1004 (e=0/0)
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123364]: debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
May 12 09:07:38 velis sshd[123364]: debug1: audit_event: unhandled event 12


I have just found that using -O (old protocol) flag solves the situation. it's not the preferred solution, though

I have also found that it's not LAN that's the issue here. Windown's clients on LAN still work. it was a DNS configuration change that was messing those up...

The scp client in recent OpenSSH versions no longer uses actual scp – it has become an SFTP client. This means your wrapper script needs to allow a completely different command; instead of the previous scp -r or such, it has to allow the command that you have listed under Subsystem sftp. In this case, your script must allow /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server to be run.
(SSH clients call the subsystem by name so that it stays the same regardless of server OS, but on the OpenSSH server side it still works exactly like a traditional command execution.)
It also means that your script can no longer distinguish between different requests, since they're all done through stdio from/to the sftp-server process. With OpenSSH, though, the sftp-server has command-line options to restrict requests – you need to run it with -Q requests to get a list of request types, then use the -p or -P options to restrict what's allowed.
if orig_cmd == "/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server":
    allowed = ["opendir", "readdir", ...]
    new_cmd = ["/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server", "-p", ",".join(allowed)]
    os.execv(new_cmd[0], new_cmd)

(If this is for a single account, then the subsystem setting should remain unchanged and your script should add the options on its own.)

Not sure: I print "Transfer shell 1.0" to stderr at the first non-import statement in the shell script and it never gets to this point with scp. it just quits with that message about connection closed
